# Distributing scripts using autotools

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I would like to distribute my startup script with my app. Its called "blah" and it resides in the scripts/ folder of my project. I have this in my configure.ac:

```
... 
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
    Makefile
    scripts/Makefile
    ....
])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([scripts/blah], [chmod +x scripts/blah])

AC_OUTPUT
```

In the scripts directory I do have the following Makefile.am:

```
dist_bin_SCRIPTS = blah
CLEANFILES = $(bin_SCRIPTS)
```

In the same dir I do have "blah.in" file.

But when I do "make install" it does create scripts/blah, bot does not install it to the /usr/local/bin directory. What is wrong with my setup? Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is being installed in /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: Nope, just a typo. Fixing, thanks. It just wont get installed in the prefix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have `AC_CONFIG_FILES([scripts/blah], ...)` to create `script/blah` from `script/blah.in` then you should only distribute `script/blah.in` (this happens automatically as a side effect of using `AC_CONFIG_FILES`) and not distribute `script/blah`.

Your `Makefile` should read

```
bin_SCRIPTS = blah   # not dist_bin_SCRIPTS
CLEANFILES = $(bin_SCRIPTS)
```

If you simply want to distribute and install the script as-is, without generating it with `configure`, use only

```
dist_bin_SCRIPTS = blah
```

and omit `CLEANFILES` as well as the `AC_CONFIG_FILES` line.

Now this is not your real bug.  Looking at your github files I can see that `scripts` does not appear in the `SUBDIRS` variable of your root `Makefile.am`.  Therefore `make install` is not recursing into that subdirectory and does not install the script.

Comment: Thanks! Works. How could I miss that!

Comment: thanks, 

      dist_bin_SCRIPTS = blah

is the solution  :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to specify:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([scripts/blah], [chmod +x scripts/blah])
```

?

For me, autotools generate blah.in, because they think, you blah script is a makefile. Try removing this line, tell what happens.

Comment: Tried dist clean, autoreconf, make. In this case scripts/blah wont get even created from the .in file.

Comment: you can try it here https://github.com/lzap/vide (its the scripts/videx startup script that is not getting installed)

Comment: You can `AC_CONFIG_FILES` any template. It doesn't have to be a `Makefile.in`.